# Create a list of Dictionaries iterating over list of input values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, while-loop, nested-loops

I'm trying to create a list of dictionaries based on separate lists of inputs.

Example:
inputs

```
appetizer = ['soup', 'salad']
entree = ['steak', 'chicken', fish']
dessert = ['ice cream', 'flan', cake']

dict = {appetizer = [], entree = [], dessert = []}

dinner_options = []
```

From here, I'd like to create a list of dictionaries with all of the possible dinner options

Output

```
dinner_options = [{appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'steak', dessert = 'ice cream'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'steak', dessert = 'flan'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'steak', dessert = 'cake'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'chicken', dessert = 'ice cream'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'chicken', dessert = 'flan'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'chicken', dessert = 'cake'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'fish', dessert = 'ice cream'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'fish', dessert = 'flan'},
                  {appetizer = 'soup', entree = 'fish', dessert = 'cake'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'steak', dessert = 'ice cream'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'steak', dessert = 'flan'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'steak', dessert = 'cake'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'chicken', dessert = 'ice cream'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'chicken', dessert = 'flan'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'chicken', dessert = 'cake'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'fish', dessert = 'ice cream'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'fish', dessert = 'flan'},
                  {appetizer = 'salad', entree = 'fish', dessert = 'cake'}]
```

Essentially, at the end I'm trying to get a list that has all of the permutations of the lists (parameters) provided in the inputs.

Comment: Is your input array are always 3 or it can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

appetizer = ['soup', 'salad']
entree = ['steak', 'chicken', 'fish']
dessert = ['ice cream', 'flan', 'cake']

# Here we create an iterable from the objects we want to obtain
# different combinations.
to_combine = (appetizer, entree, dessert)

# Next, we need to define the order in which those appear
# as those will be used as the keys in the individual
# dictionary objects.
order = 'appetizer,entree,dessert'.split(',')
dinner_options = list()

# Now we loop over the unpacked tuple and build each individual
# dictionary.
for items in product(*to_combine):
    # This creates the individual objects which are of the form:
    # `{'appetizer': '<a>', 'entree': '<e>', 'dessert': '<d>'}
    d = {key:value for key, value in zip(order, items)}
    dinner_options.append(d)
```

This yields the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to iterate over your list and append the possibilities to your `dinner_options` array.

```py
appetizer = ['soup', 'salad']
entree = ['steak', 'chicken', 'fish']
dessert = ['ice cream', 'flan', 'cake']

dinner_options = []

for ap in appetizer:
    for en in entree:
        for de in dessert:
            dinner_options.append({ "appetizer": ap, "entree": en, "dessert": de })

print(dinner_options)
```

Then it should display

```sh
[{'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'steak', 'dessert': 'ice cream'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'steak', 'dessert': 'flan'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'steak', 'dessert': 'cake'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'chicken', 'dessert': 'ice cream'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'chicken', 'dessert': 'flan'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'chicken', 'dessert': 'cake'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'fish', 'dessert': 'ice cream'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'fish', 'dessert': 'flan'}, {'appetizer': 'soup', 'entree': 'fish', 'dessert': 'cake'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'steak', 'dessert': 'ice cream'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'steak', 'dessert': 'flan'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'steak', 'dessert': 'cake'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'chicken', 'dessert': 'ice cream'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'chicken', 'dessert': 'flan'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'chicken', 'dessert': 'cake'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'fish', 'dessert': 'ice cream'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'fish', 'dessert': 'flan'}, {'appetizer': 'salad', 'entree': 'fish', 'dessert': 'cake'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is the most obvious and most time-consuming answer

```
appetizer = ['soup', 'salad']
entree = ['steak', 'chicken', 'fish']
dessert = ['ice cream', 'flan', 'cake']

# dict = {appetizer = [], entree = [], dessert = []}

dinner_options = []

for start in appetizer:
    for mid in entree:
        for end in dessert:
            data = dict(appetizer=start, entree=mid, dessert=end)
            dinner_options.append(data)

print(dinner_options)
```